# Extract public key length in bits

Tags: python, m2crypto

My goal is to develop a Python script to connect to a host and determine the Server Public key length in bits similar to running openssl:

```
(openssl s_client -connect 10.18.254.29:443)
yada yada yada
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
Server public key is 2048 bit
```

I have started this basic script:

```
from M2Crypto import SSL, RSA
SSL.Connection.clientPostConnectionCheck = None
ctx = SSL.Context()
conn = SSL.Connection(ctx)
conn.connect(('1.1.1.1', 443))
cert = conn.get_peer_cert()
print cert.get_issuer().as_text()

print cert.get_subject().as_text()
print cert.get_fingerprint()

print cert.get_pubkey().get_rsa().as_pem()
```

I can't seem to find a way to display a length attribute of the key. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

The general way is:

```
print key.size()
```

As [the docs](http://www.heikkitoivonen.net/m2crypto/api/M2Crypto.EVP.PKey-class.html) for `PKey` say, this is the size in *bytes*, not bits. So, it you want to get that "2048", you need to multiply by 8.

If you know it's RSA, and have already called `get_rsa()`, you can do this:

```
print len(rsa)
```

[The docs](http://www.heikkitoivonen.net/m2crypto/api/) don't say what this does, but it returns the length in bits.

As usual with M2Crypto, what you really need to be looking at is the libssl/libcrypto docs (not the openssl command-line tool). And, if you can't guess which C functions are getting called, the source is usually very simple.

For example, you can see that [`PKey.size()`](http://svn.osafoundation.org/m2crypto/trunk/M2Crypto/EVP.py) is:

```
def size(self):
    """
    Return the size of the key in bytes.
    """
    return m2.pkey_size(self.pkey)
```

And [`RSA.__len__`](http://svn.osafoundation.org/m2crypto/trunk/M2Crypto/RSA.py) is:

```
def __len__(self):
    return m2.rsa_size(self.rsa) << 3
```

And by the standard coding conventions within M2Crypto, `m2.rsa_size` is a SWIG wrapper around [`RSA_size`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/rsa.html).

Answer (score 2):

Based on the help from @abarnert I changed my code to the following

```
from M2Crypto import SSL, RSA

SSL.Connection.clientPostConnectionCheck = None
ctx = SSL.Context()
conn = SSL.Connection(ctx)
conn.connect(('10.18.254.29', 443))
cert = conn.get_peer_cert()

print cert.get_issuer().as_text()

print cert.get_subject().as_text()
print cert.get_fingerprint()

**def size(self):
    """
    Return the size of the key in bytes.
    """
    return m2.pkey_size(self.pkey)**
```

**print cert.get_pubkey().size()*8**